Launching the gazebo environment on Rviz
I ran a simulation on gazebo using the command roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch. I want to open the same environment in Rviz. I used the command roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_gazebo_rviz.launch. This environment is not same as the gazebo environment. How can I launch the same environment?
I used ROS noetic for the simulation.
